HealthConnect with JAVA; getGrantedPermissions() is blocking and infinite
I need to get back the current permissions for Health Connect:
Set<String> grantedPermissions = null;
    try {
        grantedPermissions = BuildersKt.runBlocking(
                EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE,
                (s, c) -> HealthConnect.getInstance(context).mHealthConnectClient.
                        getPermissionController().getGrantedPermissions(c)
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

And this call is infinite, I don't understand why.
(Android 13)

See doc https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/get-started#step-4.
